# New Badge request: Chatter Box

Tags: feature-request, badges

I want propose a new badge for the increase involvement of people in chat.

### Chatter Box:

- User should have visited and posted something on chat for 30(or more) consecutive days.
- Shouldn't have been flagged once in that period
- Could be given more than once.

Comment: Also, if this becomes a badge, maybe make it only awardable once, but also have a silver and a gold badge with higher requirements, respectively.

Comment: Another thing I see is that possibly many people will post even when they really have nothing to say, just to get the badge. I think most of the inactivity comes from this being a smaller site, and there aren't often two people on chat at once, even if they are logged on. Many people on this site are also in different time zones, which makes it worse.

Comment: @J.Musser: I like the idea for Silver. We could increase the days. If someone is posting rubbish we could flag them, if flagged the timer reset. PS: Thanks for the pointer it was a typo.

Comment: Why? Badges are just fancy.. no real purpose..

Comment: @WYSIWYG: It's just for increasing activity in chat.

Comment: but why do you want to do so.. if people are interested then they will chat. why promote unnecessary chatting?

Comment: @WYSIWYG: Mostly for the event.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Badges show where users were exceptionally helpful. They have some purpose. On GL, I have only 4 gold badges, three famous question and an electorate, showing that I vote well, and ask good questions. I almost have the copy editor badge, which will show that I have been actively cleaning up the site, and I am over three quarters of the way toward the fanatic and socratic badges, showing that I have interest in maintaining my profile, and ask many well received questions. Many of the bronze badges are also mostly incentives for new users to treat the site properly.  The thi(continued)

Comment: (continued)ng that I see as a problem with this suggested badge is that the chat feed they might add isn't necessarily going to be helpful. Low rep users may add useless chat feed, just for the sake of the badge, similar to what some people do for the fanatic badge. I don't see a particularly valuable use for this badge, as it stands proposed now, but I think an incentive to get users to properly use chat is a good thing. I disagree with your statement, "Badges are just fancy.. no real purpose.". I look at everyone's profiles when I get responses, and note which badges they have, wh(continued)

Comment: (continued)at tags they have the most rep for, and so on, to help me decide how good of a response I have gotten, especially on questions I ask on sites I am not familiar with. Badges have a place, but we must be very careful on what new badge proposals we support.

Comment: My, that was long.

Comment: @J.Musser .. The most voted answer isn't necessarily a good one.. In some cases it is but generally it is the pop-science questions and answers that get most votes- sometimes answers to those are easily obtainable by googling. Badges are good but not fully reliable.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Ah, yeah, that's why I read the answer before accepting, and research some of the information given.